# Почему показывается unity реклама вместо настоящей?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Всем привет. Почему у меня вместо настоящей рекламы показывается тестовая реклама. Enable test mode у меня выключен, но настоящая реклама не показывается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отключи тестовую рекламу в настройках и в вызове рекламы укажи, что она не тестовая.

Comment: А где в вызове указать, что она не тестовая?